# Encrypt with private and decrypt with public keys /Openssl

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, openssl, rsa

**Hi**,
Recently, I was studying about openssl.
I found that encrypting with a private key is allowed while decrypting with the public one isn't, and throws an error:
**unable to load Private Key** or **A private key is needed for this operation**

```
-----------------------------Generating Private/Public Keys--------------------------------------
$ openssl genrsa -out prv.pem 1024  ## generating a private key
$ openssl rsa -in prv.pem -pubout -out Emett_pubKey.pub  ## generating the public key

------------------------------Encrypting/Decrypting Message--------------------------------------
$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey prv.pem -in Message -out Enc_Mssg  ## Encrypt file=Message

$ openssl rsautl -decrypt -in Enc_Mssg -out Messg -inkey -pubin Emett_pubKey.pub  ## try to decrypt file=Enc_Mssg
>A private key is needed for this operation
```

I am wondering if I'm just using **openssl** in a wrong way or it must be done in a different way, something like using `-sign` instead of encrypting the Message like I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithmically, A private key can be used to decrypt a message that was encrypted using the correspoding public key, or to sign a message; but a private key cannot be used to encrypt a message.  For more information on this subject see Thomas Pornin's answer at [If the public key can't be used for decrypting something encrypted by the private key, then how do digital signatures work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87325/if-the-public-key-cant-be-used-for-decrypting-something-encrypted-by-the-privat) (and note in particular where he blames the confusion on 'deleterious effects of post-Disco pop music').

The reason that the `openssl rsautl -encrypt` command that you copied in your question works with the private key file prv.pem that you created with `openssl genrsa` is because prv.pem actually contains both the private key and the public key.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45151/anatomy-of-an-rsa-private-key for more info.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I really appreciate this.
and figuring out that private.pem also contains the public key was so interesting for me.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

*"...I am wondering if I'm just using openssl in a wrong way or it must be done in a different way, something like using -sign instead of encrypting the Message like I did."*

GPG supports that approach, it would look like this:

```
gpg --sign Message.txt
```

You will be prompted for your password and the output file *Message.txt.gpg* can be decrypted with the Public key.

```
gpg --output result.txt --decrypt Message.txt.gpg
```

No password required as the Public key is used to decrypt.